# No view found for id 0x for fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-fragments

I was following the guidelines in the book "Android Programming" by The Big Nerd Ranch. When i ran the application on my phone, it said "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Try again". This is the first lines it showed in LogCat:

```html
10-21 10:11:48.550: E/FragmentManager(6393): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent:id/fragmentContainer) for fragment CrimeFragment{4054c7d0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-21 10:11:48.550: E/FragmentManager(6393): Activity state:
```

This is where I have fragmentContainer:

```html
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class CrimeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 //Call when the activity is first created
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);
        
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        
        if (fragment == null){ 
         fragment = new CrimeFragment();
         fm.beginTransaction()
         .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
         .commit();
        } //Create a new fragment transaction, include one add operation in it, and then commit it
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crime, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the .xml file. I added this line android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" when fragmentContainer could not be resolved

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height = 'wrap_content'
        android:hint = "@string/crime_title_hint"
         />
    

</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the manifest and the rest of the java and xml files:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CrimeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

CrimeFragment.java

```html
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
 private Crime mCrime;
 private EditText mTitleField;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mCrime = new Crime();
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
   @Nullable ViewGroup parent, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // inflates fragment_crime.xml
  //onCreateView method is also the place to wire up the EditText to respond to user input
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);
  mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
  mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
   public void onTextChanged(
     CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count){
    mCrime.setTitle(c.toString()); //set title, CharSequence is user's input
   }
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count, int after){
    
   }
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable c){
    
   }
  });
  return v;
 }
 
 


}
```

Crime.java

```html
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Crime {
 private UUID mId;
 private String mTitle;
 
 public Crime()  {
  //Generate unique identifier
  mId = UUID.randomUUID();
 }

 public String getTitle() {
  return mTitle;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
  mTitle = title;
 }

 public UUID getId() {
  return mId;
 }
}
```

fragment_crime.xml and activity_crime.xml in res/layout respectively:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent.CrimeActivity" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height = 'wrap_content'
        android:hint = "@string/crime_title_hint"
         />
    

</LinearLayout>
```

crime.xml in res/menu:

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalIntent.CrimeActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

I am very new to Android App Development so every opinion is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please post your manifest and the layout xml file for your activity as well.

Comment: I have already done so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay so this code, "Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);" is a little odd. The container isn't a fragment it's a LinearLayout. I'll post an answer so I can put formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would simplify the *onCreate()* this way. The container check doesn't need it's own concrete object and it's reference type is LinearLayout not Fragment. Also you don't want to call for the fragment manager until you know you're going to need it, i.e. after the null check.

```
public class CrimeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

         if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer != null) {
             CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
         }
    }
```

Try this please.

Comment: Thank you! For the If statement I think you might have missed a close parenthesis after the R.id.fragmentContainer because it gave me an error. It worked after adding the parenthesis. However i can't access to the fragment_crime.xml. All it shows right now is the activity_crime.xml. Is that how it's supposed to be and that i should continue with the book?